# Converting a String to TXSDecimal

Tags: delphi, soap, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am trying to covert a string to a SOAP `TXSDecimal`, this is what I have currently, so the value in my edit box does not get stored inside `Foo.Limit`

```
Foo.limit := TXSDecimal(edtLimit.text);
```

PS : `Foo.Limit` is a `TXSDecimal` datatype

I have also tried

`Foo.limit.asAsBcd := edtLimit.text;` // get Access Violation

So I want to know how do you convert a `String` to a `TXSDecimal`

Comment: If it's an actual _access violation_, it's probably because `Foo.limit` isn't a valid TXSDecimal instance, but be aware that you will also get an exception when edtLimit.text is formatted incorrectly and therefore cannot be converted to BCD. When asking messages like this, please add the actual error message to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first snippet is incorrect. You're typecasting a string to TXSDecimal, which is not valid. TXSDecimal is a class, for which you need to have an instance. Once you have an instance, you can use it's properties and methods to set the value.

The second snippet is apparently incomplete. If you get an access violation, that is likely because Foo.limit is not assigned a proper TXSDecimal.

So, you can create a new instance, assign it to Foo.limit, and assign it a floating point value like so:

```
Foo.limit := TXSDecimal.Create;
Foo.limit.AsBcd := Edit1.Text;
```

You can assign a string to a BCD as above, and it will convert it to a numeric value automatically. The assignment will throw an exception (not an access violation, but a different kind) if the string doesn't contain a valid number.

This conversion will take your system settings into account, so if you're set up to use a comma as a decimal separator, you cannot enter a number that uses a period.

Comment: @GolexTrol, Thanks, I had to create Foo.limit

Answer (score 1):

Check if `Foo.limit` is assigned, if not, you could create and assign it in Foo's constructor.

Then you need to convert the `string` value in a `TBcd` value, you can use the [`FMTBcd.StrToBCD()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Data.FmtBcd.StrToBcd) function.

`Foo.Limit.AsBcd := StrToBCD(edtLimit.Text);`